# jquery function does not seem to be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

So I have my Rails 3.1 app and Im using ajax to handle login and logout. Since I have duplication of some code(appending flash notice, updating divs) I moved the code into a function and called that function from within my other methods. It works fine if I take the code out of the function and put it into the method but after i moved the code into the function it not longer does anything.

data.login looks like :json => ( :login => true)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function setNotice(data) {
    var $flash = $('<div class="alert alert-success"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">x</a>'" + data.data.message + "'</div>');
     $('#account').html( 
      if (data.login) { 
        data.email 
      } else {
        "Account"
      });
     $('.alert').alert('close');
     $('.row').prepend($flash);
  }


  $('form#sign_in').bind('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    console.log(data);
    if(data.success) {
      $('#user_login_box').html(data.content);
      setNotice(data)
    } else {
      $('#status').html(data.data.message);
    }
  });

  $('.logout').bind('click', function(e, data, status, xhr) {
   setNotice(data)
  });

});
```

Comment: What is `$('.alert').alert('close');`?

Comment: its a twitter bootstrap function to close an open alert, http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#alerts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting `$.html`, you need to use an anonymous function, and `return` results:

```
$('#account').html(function(){
  return data.login ? data.email : "Account" ;
});
```

Your `$flash` line was not properly concatenated:

```
var $flash = $('<div class="alert alert-success"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">x</a>' + data.data.message + '</div>');
```

Or rewritten:

```
var $flash = $("<div>",{
  'class': 'alert alert-success',
   'html': data.data.message
});

var $link  = $("<a>",{
   'html': 'x',
  'class': 'close',
   'href': '#'
}).data("dismiss","alert").prependTo( $flash );
```

###From the [Chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11406/discussion-between-mike-and-jonathan-sampson)

We also determined the logout button was not working:

```
$('.logout').bind('click', function(e, data, status, xhr) {
   setNotice(data);
});
```

This was the result of confusing parameters made available to click event handlers. The solution was to change the click event to fire off an asynchronous request to log the user out:

```
$(".logout").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post("/logout", {_method:"delete"}, function(data){
    setNotice(data);
  });
};
```

Comment: data.data.message are indentical for login and logout but when logout is triggered firebug console says data is undefined but it works fine for login

Comment: @Mike Test the value of `data.data.message` before you show it.

Comment: its there, "signed out successfully"

Comment: @Mike I thought you said it was coming back `undefined`?

Comment: i got firebug console up, the json response from the server is `{"success":true,"data":{"message":"Signed out successfully."},"logout":true,"login":false}` however firebug also says `"data is undefined 'html': data.data.message"` So to clarify it says all of data is undefined. Its not being passed from logout to setNotice i guess :/

Comment: @Mike I'm familiar with Firebug. I suppose if the `undefined` message isn't breaking your app, you can ignore it. If you need to serve up some message in its place, you could do `data || "No data";`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11406/discussion-between-mike-and-jonathan-sampson)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a error in the following line..

`var $flash = $('<div class="alert alert-success">  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">x</a>'" + data.data.message + "'</div>');`

can you replace the above line with this and let us know if it got solved..

`var $flash = $('<div class="alert alert-success"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">x</a>' + data.data.message + '</div>');`

can you make sure that all the quotes etc are properly closed?

Comment: yep you are right. That is what was causing + data.data.message + to be rendered into the div instead of the actual message, thanks.